# Difficulty setting ruby 3.0.2 as default version (Your Ruby version is 2.6.6, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having trouble setting ruby 3.0.2 as my default version. I have tried changing the version using the following command:
rvm --default use 3.0.2

Once I run the command and open another tab to run the console or to use to open sublime text I get the following error again: Your Ruby version is 2.6.6, but your Gemfile specified 3.0.2 even though I had already changed the default version. This keeps on happening over and over even after I reset the terminal.

Comment: The problem is the Ruby version isn't being set to 3.0.2, but as a lazy workaround, you can just remove the line in your Gemfile setting the Ruby version (same if you have a .ruby-version file)

Comment: Is there any mention of `2.6.6` in the project? For example, perhaps the `.ruby-version` file is setting it as such? Just because you've set a global default, that doesn't prevent project-specific settings to override that.

Comment: Thank you @SebastianPalma @TomLord! I changed the ruby version file and it worked.